# Error during execution Stored Process SAS

Tags: sas

I made a stored process with SAS stores process wizard. Then i need to create date range. I did it , but when i set date range after execution I get an error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to compare dates in the where clause, in which case you'll have to convert the text date to a numeric, e.g. try using:

```
where "&date_range_min"d < date_entered < "&date_range_max"d
```